# How to submit and validate a form from outside component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, components

I have a multi-step component on which I would like to have a form in one of the steps, so when the user tries to go to the next step I could validate the input and submit the form. So far I have this code, but I haven't figured how to validate and submit the code from the outside button.

I would appreciate your help.

```
import CostumForm from './NannySignupComponents/InformacionPersonal';

const steps = ['Shipping address', 'Payment details', 'Review your order'];

const theme = createTheme();

export default function Checkout() {

  function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <CostumForm/>
        );
      case 1:
        return ;
      case 2:
        return ;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown step');
    }
  }
  
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
    this.setState({submitFromOutside: true})
    
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  };

 

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="absolute"
        color="default"
        elevation={0}
        sx={{
          position: 'relative',
          borderBottom: (t) => `1px solid ${t.palette.divider}`,
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
            Company name
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm" sx={{ mb: 4 }} >
        <Paper variant="outlined" sx={{ my: { xs: 3, md: 6 }, p: { xs: 2, md: 3 } }}>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h4" align="center">
            Checkout
          </Typography>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} sx={{ pt: 3, pb: 5 }}>
            {steps.map((label) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
          <React.Fragment>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                  Thank you for your order.
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                  Your order number is #2001539. We have emailed your order
                  confirmation, and will send you an update when your order has
                  shipped.
                </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                {getStepContent(activeStep)}
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                  {activeStep !== 0 && (
                    <Button onClick={handleBack} sx={{ mt: 3, ml: 1 }} >
                      Back
                    </Button>
                  )}

                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    sx={{ mt: 3, ml: 1 }}
                  
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Place order' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        </Paper>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you return any function from useEffect closure, the returned function is executed when the component is unmounted.

like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {

    do something...

    return () => { do something to be executed when unmounted };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).